# Is it necessary to give Opt-In/Opt-Out UIAlertView for using Google Analytics in ios?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics in my ios App so is it necessary to show this(see Image) kind of Alert box to user so that he can opt out for sending data to analytics.

As we are sending data to 3rd party( Google), I just want to make sure we are not violating any Apple policies.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sample purpose the google analytics show this message. In real time no need of this, in every 30 minutes the session automatically cleared. If you want to close the session in manually use optout for stop the tracking else part no need of this.

If you are use the analytics and submit the app in appstore , the apple does not reject your app. I used google anaytics in my apps. The app also availabe in app store

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: Ya sure i used analytics in my three apps name as outt, realtime rugby, twosum.

Comment: If you need the additional help i surely hope with you